# Prove there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=BA$ and $B^2 = -I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix without real eigenvalues.
>
> Prove there exists a real matrix $B$ such that $AB=BA$ and $B^2 = -I$.

I understand that $n$ is even and $A$ is a nonsingular  matrix.

Comment: You need to impose more conditions on $A$. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -2\\
2 & \phantom{-}0 \end{pmatrix}$ as a counter-example.

Comment: @parsiad Let $$B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Oh, I misread the question; for some reason I thought it required $AB=BA=I$ (i.e., $B$ is $A$'s inverse). Ignore my comment.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you have this problem from? If it's from a class, how much linear algebra was already covered in that class?

Comment: This question was previously asked, and answered with a different argument, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261286/real-matrix-without-real-eigenvalues-commutes-with-some-matrix-of-square-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real matrix without real eigenvalues commutes with some matrix of square $-I$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261286/real-matrix-without-real-eigenvalues-commutes-with-some-matrix-of-square-i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true. We assume that $n$ is even.

Let $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. We consider the real Jordan form of $A$. Its Jordan blocks are in the form of this $2r\times 2r$ matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}aI_2+bJ&I_2&0\cdots&0\\0&aI+bJ&I
&0\cdots\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\0&\cdots&0&aI+bJ\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R},b\not= 0$.

It suffices to show the existence of $B$ when $A$ is reduced to one Jordan block.

It suffices to choose $B=diag(J_1,\cdots,J_r)$ where $J_k=J$.